# iPhone imageView layer masksToBound leads to slow scrolling

Tags: iphone, core-animation, uiimageview, calayer

I have a `UITableView` with about 30 cells, 5 are viewable at a time.
In each cell I have 2 `UILabels` and 1 `UIImageView`.

I use a CALayer to render the image view with a rounded border.

```
    myImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.5;
    myImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    myImageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
```

Particually the line `masksToBounds` makes the scroll speed extremely slow on the device.
I can't wrap my head around subclassing cells and drawRect myself. (I failed after wanting NSStrings with 2 lines)

Anyway is there a way to use CALayers masksToBounds without that performance hit?

Comment: Something that may help is checking to see if the slowdown is caused by the layer animation. I don't know exactly how to check this for your case, but I had something similar happen to me. Once I disabled the animations it worked just fine.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean? How do I disable animations? That code shown is the only CALayer code I have in my app.

Comment: Change the layer.speed to something ridiculously high like 20. Does it speed up? I am still learning how to actually disable the animations myself, unfortunately, so I cannot help you there. Setting the speed will help identify if the animation is causing the slowdown but it is not a good permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

On December 12th 2008, the maker of the Tweetie IPhone App posted a great example how he accomplishes `UITableView` scrolling without the jagged/raggedness that normally entails.

See this post:

[Fast Scrolling in Tweetie with UITableView](http://web.archive.org/web/20100322222950/http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/)

Comment: That link is no longer available. The post can be found archived at http://web.archive.org/web/20100322222950/http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/